# How can I get TOP photos from Flickr

Tags: ios, flickr

I'm using `Flickr API: flickr.photos.search` in my app and couldn't find any argument which will return TOP photos. 
Is there other search which can I use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added to sort by interestingness-desc in flickr.photos.search api.

```
[FlickrAPIRequest callAPIMethodWithGET:@"flickr.photos.search"
                           arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 @"interestingness-desc", @"sort", nil]];
```